# how to access input box values with comma separated values and save to the database

Tags: php

This is My PHP code till now I tried

```
<?php
include_once("../include/connClass.php");
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

if(isset($_POST["save"]))
{
 $date = $_POST["txtDate1"];
}

$date = $_POST["txtDate1"];
$service = $_POST["txtService1"];
$charge = $_POST["txtCharge1"];
$amount = $_POST["txtAmount1"];
$unit = $_POST["txtUnit1"];
$total = $_POST["txtTotal1"];

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($date); $i++) {

  try {
        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO backup_master (backup_date, 
backup_service, backup_charge, backup_amount, backup_unit, backup_total)
            VALUES (:backup_date, :backup_service, :backup_charge, 
:backup_amount, :backup_unit, :backup_total)");

        $sql->bindParam(':backup_date', $date);
        $sql->bindParam(':backup_service', $service);
        $sql->bindParam(':backup_charge', $charge);
        $sql->bindParam(':backup_amount', $amount);
        $sql->bindParam(':backup_unit', $unit);
        $sql->bindParam(':backup_total', $total);

        $query = $sql->execute();
        // echo $query;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br />Error" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

this is my form code

```
<form method="POST" action="backend/save.php">

<input type="text" id="txtDate1" name="txtDate1">
<input type="text" id="txtService1" name="txtService1">
<input type="text" id="txtCharge1" name="txtCharge1">
<input type="text" id="txtAmount1" name="txtAmount1">
<input type="text" id="txtUnit1" name="txtUnit1">
<input type="text" id="txtTotal1" name="txtTotal1">

<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is my question is I have an input boxes values with comma separated and I want to insert values one by one to the different rows to the database but now 
all comma separated values are inserting into the single row any idea how to do Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please update your question by providing the code for the form and more detail. At the moment we don't even know which POST variable contains the comma separated values

Comment: Bro, i have updated the form element.

Comment: all POST variable contains comma separted values

Answer (score 0):

to broad question. you can explode string using `explode` function

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="dataString">
```

**PHP**

```
$dataString=$_GET['dataString'];
$testArray = explode(',', $dataString);
print_r($testArray);
```

Comment: bro, I want to insert values into different rows my data is like a,ayz,abc   in this I want to insert a in the first row, ayz in the second row, abc in the 3rd row

Comment: it's simple use loop `for(i=0;i<3;i++)` first time you insert `$testArray[0]` and second time `$testArray[1]` and third time `$testArray[2]`

Comment: bro, I am doing that way only in my code,  otherwise if wrong please show in your code.